# StartsWith extension method for stream

Tags: c#, .net

I want to write a `bool StartsWith(string message)` extension method for a stream. What is the most efficient way?

Comment: To begin with, you need to be more specific, do you mean you want a stream to have an extension mirroring the functionality of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx

Comment: @Seph; i want to write a .net extension method for Stream. The link you gave is of string.

Answer (score 2):

Start with something like this ...

```
public static bool StartsWith(Stream stream this, string value)
{
  using(reader = new StreamReader(stream))
  {
    string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return str.StartsWith(value);
  }
}
```

Then optimise ... I'll leave this as an exercise for you, `StreamReader` has various [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8.aspx) methods which will allow you to read the stream in smaller 'chunks' for a more efficient result.

Comment: The `using StreamReader` is not a good idea in this case as it will close the stream when the reader is disposed which will very likely be unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

```
static bool StartsWith(this Stream stream, string value, Encoding encoding, out string actualValue)
{
    if (stream == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("stream"); }
    if (value == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("value"); }
    if (encoding == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("encoding"); }

    stream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    int count = encoding.GetByteCount(value);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[count];
    int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, count);

    actualValue = encoding.GetString(buffer, 0, read);

    return value == actualValue;
}
```

*Of course a `Stream` itself does not imply that it's data is decodable to a string representation. If you're sure your stream is, you can use the extension above.*